# Текст и кнопка в одной ячейке DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, я еще новичок в WPF. Есть таблица в которой есть вот такая вот ячейка:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Время">
       <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
              <MultiBinding>
                     <Binding Path="Color" />
                     <Binding Path="Time" />
              </MultiBinding>
       </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Color - задает цвет ячейки, Time - пишет время. Мне нужно добавить кнопку "Изменить время" в эту ячейку, которая будет находиться под текстом с временем и на которую можно будет повешать binding. Как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про DataGridTemplateColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Время">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" />
                <Button Content="{Binding ChangeTime}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```